# Exception thrown when setting HorizontalScroll Minimum, Maximum, and Values?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I am creating a UserControl-derived control (call it "Panel") that contains within it a ScrollPanel named scrollPanel.  During the constructor for the "Panel" UserControl, after calling InitializeComponent(), I construct another UserControl-derived control (call it "Viewer") that  is added to scrollpanel.Controls.

Without waiting for any message loops to process, I then call

```
scrollPanel.HorizontalScroll.Minimum = 0;
scrollPanel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 1000;
scrollPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value = 800;
```

and get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

I guess I have to wait to set the scroll bar value until it's done creating itself?  How can I do that in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Set your the AutoScroll property to false:

```
scrollPanel.AutoScroll = false;
scrollPanel.HorizontalScroll.Minimum = 0;
scrollPanel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 1000;
scrollPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value = 800;
```

Comment: This works!  But I don't know wny.  The Microsoft documentation seems to be written in some language very similar to English.  It talks about two things in a jumbled fashion - (1) scroll bars appearing automatically, and (2) the ability to scroll to controls not currently on the screen (which is, after all, the whole point of the ScrollPanel).

Comment: @BettyCrokker Your code is basically telling the container to not worry about the scrollbars, "I'll take care of it".